# What type of controller is this?

Tags: microcontroller, power, converter

In many simple microcontroller power controller applications, I see controllers that work in an "increment/decrement" on error with hysteresis implemented e.g.

```
if(targetvoltage<errorvoltage) PWM_Output++;
else if(targetvoltage>(errorvoltage+hysteresis)) PWM_Output--;
SetPWMOutput(PWM_Output);
```

It seems to be somewhere between a bang bang controller and a PI controller (error is integrated kind of and stored in PWM_Output, P scaling is most likely done by the transistor driver) but its not quite either. What kind of controller would this be?

Obviously its not a particularly fast controller but it seems to work OK for some of the applications I've tried.

Comment: Looks like it integrates to me, just not that quickly.

Comment: Yeh, I got that kind of feel too, It just seems like it does more than just integrate.

Comment: The "dead band" introduced by the `hysteresis` variable makes the system nonlinear, so it's hard to give it a generic classification. Sometimes this sort of optimization is done in order to prevent the output from making continual tiny adjustments, which can cause excess power consumption. The tradeoff is having to tolerate a larger instantaneous error at least some of the time. Using increment/decrement also imposes a rate-of-change limitation on the output, which can be important in some situations.

Comment: @Dave: The fixed slope by itself already makes this controller non-linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any particular name for this kind of controller.

The advantages of a fixed-slope system are great simplicity and inherent stability in most cases.  As long as the output has settled a good way to the new steady steady state each loop iteration, the system will be stable and it won't overshoot.  The drawback is that response is slow compared to more sophisticated control methods using the same plant.

The hysteresis prevents the system from "hunting" around the setpoint and avoids constant small tweaks.

This kind of controller is useful when the thing being controlled and the input signal are largely intended to be fixed.  The controller is then compensating for variations due to temperature, wear, and the like, not actively trying to put a specific "signal" on the output.

Note that this system is NOT a integrator.  A real integrator adds a fraction of the offset (desired - actual) to the control signal each iteration.  This system adds a constant regardless of how far off the output is from the desired level.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed regulator is I controller with half of dead band. Usually the dead band is symetric, while in this case is not. The author is probably a student without big knowledge in control theory, it's just a heuristic programming approach with guessing. Technicaly speaking, this controller doesn't worth to be deeply analyzed.

EDIT: 
Olin Lathrop gave the best explanation, so it's not an I controller. It's more an enhanced two level controller. 
Cons: the actual value will tend to oscilate near resonant frequency with large overshoots, how large is subject to system behaviour.
Pros: The control loop is always stable.

Comment: No, this is not a "I controller" or integrator.  See last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You are correct, I have edited the answer.